# Where did Lauren Ψ go?

Tags: discussion, editing, site-promotion

I realized that I still have more edits than Lauren, surprisingly.  I also couldn't remember the last time I'd seen her edit, so I checked [her activity page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11387/lauren?tab=activity), which shows that she hasn't edited anything for 24 days now.  Where did she go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lauren was only ever supposed to look at the top 1000 questions (by views). Which she did.

Quoting [the meta Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character):

> Before they start to promote a site, [the CHAOS team] will spend a couple of days sweeping up a little bit just to get the place in order. This is the world's most superficial cleanup: they're just looking at the top 1000 questions in order by page views and, if necessary, editing the titles to make them more grammatical, fix spelling, and make them reflect the gist of the question better.

And further:

> They also have temporary diamonds while they do these edits so that their edits don't just go into a queue to annoy the real mods, but those are temporary and will go away when this editing project is done.

And in case you haven't noticed, Lauren's diamond *is* [gone](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11387/lauren?tab=stats).

Comment: I never noticed the diamond.  Hmm.

Comment: +1 For saying that diamond *is* gone.